# R: problems when trying to avoid one looping in implementations like matrix1[i, j]

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to work in a different kind of implementation that I would generally use. I'm trying to avoid one loop by replacing the "which line i of the object" with a vector of the dimnames of the lines in the object. Let's say:

```
#imagine that I have a dataset with repeated measures (2 measures of each subject)
id <- matrix(c("Subj1", "Subj1", "Subj2", "Subj2", "Subj3", "Subj3"), ncol=1)
days = 3
Weight <- matrix(0, nrow=length(id), ncol=Weight+1, dimnames=list(id, NULL))
initial.weight <- c(72,80,45,60,62,75)
Weight[,1] <- initial.weight
for (j in 1:days) #I'm trying to avoid for (i in 1:length(id))
Weight[id,j+1] <- Weight[id,j] + 2
```

But, my 2nd, 3rd, and 6th lines are returning the same zeros from my initial Weight matrix! This is because my code is only working with the first measure of a given subject. Of course, I want it to work with all lines.

Anyone know what is going on? how can I make it to work for all two measures of each subject (but still keeping this structure of [id,j] instead of [i,j])?

many thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. No Weight variable...

Comment: Do you want to add the same value to the whole vector? If so you have to leave the row index empty: `Weight[,j+1] <- Weight[,j]+2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't actually say what you wanted as the result, so I'm making two guesses. The first is that you meant to type `ncol=days+1` where you put `ncol=Weight+1`, and the second is that you wanted to serial add 2 to all the column values. So just omit the id index and it will work as I think you expected it to:

```
 for (j in 1:days) 
    Weight[ ,j+1] <- Weight[ ,j] + 2
 Weight
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
Subj1   72   74   76   78
Subj1   80   82   84   86
Subj2   45   47   49   51
Subj2   60   62   64   66
Subj3   62   64   66   68
Subj3   75   77   79   81
```

Comment: thank you for your note. Yes, I was wrong on Weight+1. I'm sorry for that. I guess I was just overthinking my problem here. [,j+1] works without specifying the lines of a matrix.